# SwiftUI Button Dynamic SF Symbol

Tags: swift, xcode, button, swiftui

I would like to give the user the possibility to mark as preferred some films in a list of films. I wrote this code but when I click on the icon the symbol does not update.

What is the right way to do this?

the main class FIlmJSON is set as ObservableObject and allFilms is set as published

**Film.swift**

```
class Film: Codable, Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    
    var id: UUID {
        return UUID()
    }
    var filmname: String?
    var developer: String?
    var dilution: String?
    var iso: String?
    var mm35: String?
    var mm120: String?
    var temperature: String?
    var brand: String?
    var type: String?
    var note: String?
    
}

// Avoid dealing with optional
extension Film {
    var _filmname: String {
        return filmname ?? ""
    }
    
    var _developer: String {
        return developer ?? ""
    }
    
    var _dilution: String {
        return dilution ?? ""
    }
    
    var _iso: String {
        return iso ?? ""
    }
    
    var _mm35: String {
        return mm35 ?? ""
    }
    
    var _mm120: String {
        return mm120 ?? ""
    }
    
    var _temperature: String {
        return temperature ?? ""
    }
    
    var _brand: String {
        return brand ?? ""
    }
    
    var _type: String {
        return type ?? ""
    }
    
    var _note: String {
        return note ?? ""
    }
    
    
    
}
```

**FilmJSON.swift**

```
class FilmJSON: Codable, ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var filmName: String
    var films: [Film]
    var isPreferred: Bool
    
    init(filmName: String, films: [Film], isPreferred: Bool) {
        self.filmName = filmName
        self.films = films
        self.isPreferred = isPreferred
    }
```

**Catalogue.swift**

```
@Published var allFilms: [FilmJSON] = []
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(catalogue.allFilms) { film in
                        HStack {
                            
                            Button {
                                film.isPreferred.toggle()
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: film.isPreferred ? "star.fill" : "star")
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                            
                            NavigationLink(destination: DeveloperView(film: film)) {
                                Text("\(film.filmName)")
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: `isPreferred` or the *film* object must be a publisher.

Comment: allFilms is the publisher. In mu code I have ``` @Published var allFilms: [FilmJSON] = [] ```

Comment: Arrays of ObservableObjects will not work as expected. I'd refactor so that you have *one* ObservableObject that stores an array of `struct`s. If you include enough for a [mre], someone can show you how to do this.

Comment: I have added a couple of details, but the code is quire simple. Also, if I change tab and I go back the image on the button change, is like the UI is not refreshed for the Button

Comment: It's not about the code being simple -- if you need someone to show you how to do the fix, you want to make the job as easy as possible for them -- something they can copy/paste and fix to show you. Right now, there's too much to stub out. But, again, the array of ObservableObjects strategy will not work as expected, as the View doesn't know to look for changes in the array.

Comment: Done, but this is the code and the array update is working. I added for testing the possibility to delete a element of the array and the list reflects the change, the modification of the array is published and the list update immediately once I delete the element

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that you are not updating the state of "film.isPreferred".

I guess that you are using a viewmodel and in this viewmodel you have to set the object or your array of the objects as a @Published variable.

For example :

```
@Published var foo : Foo
```

After this you will be able to change the value.

Comment: allFilms is the publisher. In mu code I have ``` @Published var allFilms: [FilmJSON] = [] ```

Comment: Is `FilmJSON` an `ObservableObject`?